# Using browser native "back" button to close a modal window with JS

Tags: javascript

I have created several windows modal on my site which works perfectly on desktop. I would like to improve the user experience on mobile, by allowing the user to leave the modal window by clicking on the native "back" button of the mobile browser.

I've done some research on the web, and most of the time I find answers for React, or with libraries I don't use.

Do you have any idea how to make this possible in vanilla Javascript?

Thanks a lot for your help, here is the fiddle of my code

```js
setupWaitingListModal();
    function setupWaitingListModal() {
        let waitingListLink = document.querySelector("#waitingList");
        let waitingListModal = document.querySelector("#waitingListModal");
        let waitingListCloseButton = document.querySelector('#waitingListCloseButton');

        function toggleWaitingListModal() {
            waitingListModal ? waitingListModal.classList.toggle("show-modal") : null;
            body.classList.toggle("noscroll");
        }

        if (waitingListLink) {
            waitingListLink.addEventListener("click", toggleWaitingListModal);
        }
        if (waitingListCloseButton) {
            waitingListCloseButton.addEventListener('click', toggleWaitingListModal)
        }
    }
```

```css
/* http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ 
   v2.0 | 20110126
   License: none (public domain)
*/

html,
body,
div,
span,
applet,
object,
iframe,
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6,
p,
blockquote,
pre,
a,
abbr,
acronym,
address,
big,
cite,
code,
del,
dfn,
em,
img,
ins,
kbd,
q,
s,
samp,
small,
strike,
strong,
sub,
sup,
tt,
var,
b,
u,
i,
center,
dl,
dt,
dd,
ol,
ul,
li,
fieldset,
form,
label,
legend,
table,
caption,
tbody,
tfoot,
thead,
tr,
th,
td,
article,
aside,
canvas,
details,
embed,
figure,
figcaption,
footer,
header,
hgroup,
menu,
nav,
output,
ruby,
section,
summary,
time,
mark,
audio,
video {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 100%;
  font: inherit;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article,
aside,
details,
figcaption,
figure,
footer,
header,
hgroup,
menu,
nav,
section {
  display: block;
}
body {
  line-height: 1;
}
ol,
ul {
  list-style: none;
}
blockquote,
q {
  quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before,
blockquote:after,
q:before,
q:after {
  content: "";
  content: none;
}
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
}


html {
  font-family: "Circular Std";
  -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  scroll-behavior: smooth !important;
}

body {
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: white;
}

b {
  font-weight: bold !important;
  display: contents;
}

.primary-color {
  color: #3ce7e3 !important;
}

.primary-color-dark {
  color: #009aae !important;
}

.dark-grey {
  color: #7384a7 !important;
}

.black {
  color: #002832;
}

.dark-black {
  color: black !important;
}

.width-100 {
  width: 100% !important;
}

.padding-0 {
  padding: 0 !important;
}

.padding-bottom-0 {
  padding-bottom: 0 !important;
}

.padding-top-2 {
  padding-top: 2rem;
}

.padding-top-10 {
  padding-top: 10rem !important;
}

.padding-bottom-10 {
  padding-bottom: 10rem !important;
}

.margin-left-1 {
  margin-left: 1rem;
}

.margin-right-1 {
  margin-right: 1rem;
}

.margin-top-1 {
  margin-top: 1rem;
}

.margin-bottom-1 {
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

.margin-left-2 {
  margin-left: 2rem;
}

.margin-right-2 {
  margin-right: 2rem;
}

.margin-top-2 {
  margin-top: 2rem;
}

.margin-bottom-2 {
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
}

.margin-top-4 {
  margin-top: 4rem;
}

.margin-bottom-4 {
  margin-bottom: 4rem;
}

.margin-top-6 {
  margin-top: 6rem;
}

.margin-bottom-6 {
  margin-bottom: 6rem;
}

.padding-bottom-8 {
  padding-bottom: 8rem;
}

.padding-top-8 {
  padding-top: 8rem;
}

.app-right-left-padding {
  padding: 0 11.5%;
}

.font-weight-unset {
  font-weight: unset !important;
}

.header-section {
  padding-bottom: 4rem;
}

.banner {
  background: #D7FFFE;
    border-radius: 20px;
    padding: 6px 0px;
    color: #009AAE;
    line-height: 20px;
    width: 100%;
}

.error {
  color: #d92f45;
    display: flex;
    padding-top: 8px;
}

.noscroll {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.text-font-30 {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 30px;
  line-height: 36px;
  letter-spacing: 0.3px;
}

.text-font-24 {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 30px;
  letter-spacing: 0.3px;
}

.text-font-16 {
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 22px;
  letter-spacing: 0.3px;
}

/* required for wordpress START */
.max-width-100 {
  max-width: 100% !important;
}

.site-info {
  display: none;
}

.site-main {
  margin: 0 !important;
  padding: 0 !important;
}

#colophon {
  display: none;
}

.cli-plugin-button {
  border-radius: 8px !important;
}

#bitnami-banner {
  display: none;
}

/* Cookie modal CSS override */
.cli-modal .cli-modal-close:hover {
  background-color: rgb(0, 154, 174) !important;
}

.cli-tab-footer .wt-cli-privacy-accept-btn {
  background-color: rgb(0, 154, 174) !important;
  border-radius: 8px !important;
}

.cli-tab-footer .wt-cli-privacy-accept-btn:hover {
  color: #ffffff !important;
}

.cli-switch input:checked + .cli-slider {
  background-color: rgb(0, 154, 174) !important;
}

/* Cookie modal CSS override ends here*/

/* required for wordpress END */

header {
  position: fixed;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  z-index: 9999999;
  background: white;
}

.waiting-list-section {
  padding-top: 15px;
}

.header-content {
  padding: 0 11.5%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  text-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.header-content .logo img {
  height: 30px;
}

.logo-mobile {
  visibility: hidden;
}

.header-content .menu-section {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  text-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin-top: 15px;
}

.header-content .menu-section .link .current_page_item > a {
color: #3ce7e3;
}

.header-second-part {
  width: 100%;
}

.third-part-header {
  display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.language-button {
  flex-direction: row;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  border: 0.5px solid #D4DAE6;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 20px;
  padding: 3px 8px 3px 23px;
}


.Language {
  display: none;
}

.lang-item {
  list-style: none;
  padding-right: 4px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 20px;
  padding-left: 5px;
  border: none;
  padding-top: 0;
}

.lang-item-first {
  border: none;
}

.lang-item.current-lang {
  display: none;
}



/* .header-content .menu-section .link {
  margin-left: 3rem;
} */


/* New waiting list page ends here */

/* Dropdown menu starts here */


  font-family: 'circular-std-book';
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #002832;
}

.wp-block-latest-posts .wp-block-latest-posts__post-excerpt, .wp-block-latest-posts .wp-block-latest-posts__post-full-content {
  font-family: 'circular-std-book';
}

.columns-2 {
  max-width: 730px;
  margin-top: 3rem;
}

.blog-page-title {
  padding-top: 10rem;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 48px;
  line-height: 60px;
  letter-spacing: 0.3px;
  color: #002832;
  text-align: left;
  max-width: 1110px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.page-numbers {
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.blog-page-subtitle {
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 30px;
  letter-spacing: 0.3px;
  color: #002832;
  text-align: left;
  max-width: 1100px;
  margin: 2rem auto 0 auto;
  border-bottom: 1px solid;
  padding-bottom: 2rem;
}

.navigation .nav-links {
  display:flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.pagination .nav-links > *:last-child {
  margin-right: 5px;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.pagination .nav-links > * {
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-left: 10px;
}


.pagination .nav-links > *.next {
  margin-left: 0;
}

.pagination .nav-links > *.prev {
  margin-right: 0;;
}

.wp-post-image {
  border-radius: 20px;
  width: 100%;

}

.authored-by {
  padding-left: 20px;
  color: #3c3d3e;
  line-height: 28px;
  font-size: 16px;
  letter-spacing: -0.3px;
  text-align: right;
}

.author {
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #009AAE;
}

.posted-on {
  font-size: 11px;
  line-height: 15px;
  letter-spacing: -0.3px;
  color: #7384A7;
  border: 0.5px solid #D4DAE6;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 20px;
  padding: 6px 12px 6px 12px;
  margin-right: 10px;

}

.entry-date {
  line-height: 15px;
  letter-spacing: -0.3px;
  color: #7384A7;
  }

  .span-reading-time {
    font-size: 11px;
    line-height: 15px;
    letter-spacing: -0.3px;
    color: #7384A7;
    border: 0.5px solid #D4DAE6;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border-radius: 20px;
    padding: 6px 12px 6px 12px;
    margin-right: 10px;
  }

.type-post > .authored-by {
  display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    font-size: 16px;
}

.tag-container {
  padding-top: 5px;
}

.post-attribute {
position: absolute;
margin-top: 0;
bottom: 0;
display: flex;
flex-direction: row;
}

.excerpt-wrapper .entry-content > p {
  font-size: 16px;
}

.post-attribute-page {
  display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-between;
    max-width: 720px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0 10px;
}

.mytag {
  font-size: 11px;
  line-height: 15px;
  letter-spacing: -0.3px;
  color: #7384A7;
  border: 0.5px solid #D4DAE6;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 20px;
  padding: 6px 12px 6px 12px;
  background: #F2F4F8;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.button-redirection {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 22px;
  text-align: right;
  letter-spacing: 0.3px;
  color: #002832;
  border: 1px solid #002832;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 12px 8px 13px 12px;
  width: 200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.more-info-img {
  vertical-align: bottom;
}

.vector  {
  vertical-align: middle;
}

#waitingListCloseButton {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.waiting-list-modal-box {
  position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    background-color: #ffffff;
    padding: 1.5rem 2rem 1.5rem;
    width: 790px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 10px rgb(221 227 240 / 70%);
}


.waiting-list-modal-header {
text-align: end;
}

.modal-form-title {
  max-width: 380px;
  text-align: left;
}

#nameInput7,
#emailInput7,
#nameInput8,
#emailInput8
 {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 6px 0;
}

.modal-form-container {
  text-align: left;
  margin: auto 0;
}

.first-part-modal {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.form-modal {
  padding: 26px 0 0;
}

.bonusprogram-modal {
  max-width: 730px;
  padding: 1.5rem;
  text-align: left;
  background: #F2F4F8;
  border-radius: 20px;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 20px;
  align-items: center;
  letter-spacing: -0.3px;
  color: #009AAE;
  margin-top: 1.5rem;
}

@media  (max-width: 800px) {
  .waiting-list-modal-box {
    width:400px;
  }

  .first-part-modal {
    flex-direction: column;
  }

  .modal-form-title {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 1.5rem 0 0 0;
  }
}


/* CSS for modals ends here */


@media only screen and (min-width: 652px) {
    :root {
        --responsive--aligndefault-width: min(calc(100vw - 2 * var(--global--spacing-horizontal)), 700px);
    }
}

/* Blog Page styles ends here  */


/* CSS for mobile screens */



 
/* CSS for mobile screens ends here */


/* CSS for modals starts here */

#waitingList, #waitingListEn {
  color: #009AAE;
}

.modal {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #7384a7;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  z-index: 999999999;
  max-width: 100% !important;
  margin: 0;
}

.modal-box {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background-color: #ffffff;
  padding: 1.5rem 2rem 3rem;
  width: 60%;
  border-radius: 20px;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 10px rgba(221, 227, 240, 0.7);
}

.close-button {
  width: 1rem;
  height: 1rem;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
  color: #7384a7;
}

.show-modal {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  transform: scale(1);
  overflow-y: scroll;
  background-color: rgba(115, 132, 167, 0.9);
}

.modal-header {
  height: 40px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: baseline;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.modal-header h1 {
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 30px;
  letter-spacing: 0.3px;
  color: #002832;
}

.modal-content {
  border-top: 1px solid #7e8fb0;
  padding-top: 1.5rem;
}

.modal-graph-exp {
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 20px;
  letter-spacing: -0.3px;
  color: #002832;
  padding: 1rem 1rem 2rem 1rem;
}

.modal-graph-warn {
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 20px;
  letter-spacing: -0.3px;
  color: #002832;
  background: #F2F4F8;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.modal-content .content-with-two-section {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 0 !important;
}

.modal-content .content-with-two-section .left-content-with-image {
  width: 35%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.modal-content .content-with-two-section .right-content-with-text {
  width: 60%;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 22px;
  letter-spacing: 0.3px;
  color: #002832;
}

.modal-content .content-with-two-section p {
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

.modal-content .content-with-two-section ul {
  padding-left: 1.5rem;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

.modal-content .content-with-two-section ul li {
  list-style: disc;
}

@media (max-width: 502px) {
```

```html
<a id="waitingList">modal</a>
 <div class="modal" id="waitingListModal">
            <div class="waiting-list-modal-box">
                <div class="waiting-list-modal-header">  
                    <img src="x.svg" id="waitingListCloseButton" alt="close">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [History API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API) for this, i.e. the `window.onpopstate` event handler in combination with `window.history.pushState()`:

```
function showDialog() {
  window.history.pushState({ isPopup: true }, 'Some Title');

  // Place code here / add CSS class
}

function hideDialog() {
  // Place code here / remove CSS class
}

// Call this function in order to close the dialog via the button -
// it will invoke the "onpopstate" event handler
function closeDialog() {
  window.history.back();
}

window.addEventListener('popstate', event => {
  if (event.state?.isPopup) {
    hideDialog();
  }
});
```